# Use custom classloader to transform loaded bytecode

Tags: scala, sbt, classloader

I'd like to define a ClassLoader that would selectively add methods to loaded classes. I've searched for tutorials but found no suitable example.

There are some things unclear about the process.

1. What class should I extend to define custom class loader? Scala uses own ClassLoader, so it should differ from java examples
2. How can I tell sbt to use custom ClassLoader?
3. How to bootstrap scala correctly? I want to use scala for system ClassLoader but loading scala classes requires a classloader beforehand.